# Is there any way to use Angular percent pipe without sign?

Tags: angular2-pipe

I am trying to format the value with percent pipe in html(Angular2) and i need the percentage value without % sign

Comment: Multiply with 100, use decimal pipe.

Comment: Did you figure this out? As a clarification, I came across this when I use the percent pipe to format my value in the field. So the "input" is 97 (for 97%) for example. Before sending the value in the pipe, I divide by 100. All displays well. But when I change the value, if I leave the % in the input, out comes the value 96%, and not just 96. As I try to cast to Number in my Typescript, I get problems. I'm looking for a "percent pipe reversal" ?

Answer (score 1):

As @Amadan commented in your question, you can use `number` pipe instead of `percent` pipe and multiply your value by 100. Like this:

```
{{ value * 100 | number }}
```

See this [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-percent-pipe) sample